# Корректное подключение функций PrimeFaces

Tags: java, primefaces

Как правильно в данном случае подключать функции PrimeFaces? Требуется изменить `h:dataTable` на `f:dataTable`, а второе не воспринимает `headerClass` и `ColumnClasses`...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
   <h:head>
      <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
      <title>#{msgs.pageTitle}</title>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
      <h:form>              
         <h:dataTable value="#{customerBean.all}" var="customer"
                      styleClass="customers" headerClass="customersHeader"
                      columnClasses="name, text">
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.customerIdHeader}</f:facet>
               #{customer.id}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.NDOKHeader}</f:facet>
               #{customer.NDOK}
            </h:column>
                         <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.SODRABHeader}</f:facet>
               #{customer.SODRAB}
            </h:column>
         </h:dataTable>
      </h:form>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

Код бина -

```
package com.corejsf;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.inject.Named; 
   // or import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped; 
   // or import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;

@Named // or @ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class CustomerBean {
   @Resource(name="jdbc/microsoft_sqlserver2005_resource")
   private DataSource ds;

   public ResultSet getAll() throws SQLException {
      Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
      try {
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();    
         ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("Select top 10 ID, NDOK, SODRAB FROM Table1.dbo.Base1 ");
         // return ResultSupport.toResult(result);
         CachedRowSet crs = new com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl();         
            // or use an implementation from your database vendor
         crs.populate(result);
         return crs;
      } finally {
         conn.close();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: что за f:dataTable? может p?

Answer (score 1):

У PrimeFaces есть [отличная документация](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html), четко описывающая используемые CSS-классы.

В вашем случае, например, можно переопределить такой класс:

```
.ui-datatable-header {
    background: url(../images/myImage.png)
}
```

Напрмер, [в инструкции](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf) версии 5.3 описаны стили, которые нужно переопределить в CSS для настройки скина DataTable:

`.ui-datatable`
Main container element

`.ui-datatable-data`
Table body

`.ui-datatable-empty-message`
Empty message row

`.ui-datatable-header`
Table header

`.ui-datatable-footer`
Table footer

`.ui-sortable-column`
Sortable columns

`.ui-sortable-column-icon`
Icon of a sortable icon

`.ui-expanded-row-content`
Content of an expanded row

`.ui-row-toggler`
Row toggler for row expansion

`.ui-editable-column`
Columns with a cell editor

`.ui-cell-editor`
Container of input and output controls of an editable cell

`.ui-cell-editor-input`
Container of input control of an editable cell

`.ui-cell-editor-output`
Container of output control of an editable cell

`.ui-datatable-even`
Even numbered rows

`.ui-datatable-odd`
Odd numbered rows

`.ui-datatable-scrollable`
Main container element of a scrollable table.

`.ui-datatable-scrollable-header`
Header wrapper of a scrollable table.

`.ui-datatable-scrollable-header-box`
Header container of a scrollable table.

`.ui-datatable-scrollable-body`
Body container of a scrollable table.

`.ui-datatable-scrollable-footer`
Footer wrapper of a scrollable table.

`.ui-datatable-scrollable-footer-box`
Footer container of a scrollable table.

`.ui-datatable-resizable`
Main container element of a resizable table.

`.ui-datatable-frozencolumn`
Frozen column

Comment: Тут вроде дело не совсем в CSS... если файл со стилями удалить - таблица все равно будет, вернее - данные в колонках.

Comment: Можете собрать рабочий минимальный пример проблемы? Или как-то более подробно описать проблему. Сейчас ничего не понятно. Из вопроса я понял, что вы поменяли h:dataTable на p:dataTable, и не нашли у него headerClass. И не найдете. Для этого нужно использовать css, а какой конкретно класс в css нужно править - написано выше.

Comment: Разобрался, это действительно всего лишь стили) А проблема вот в чем - после замены h:dataTable на p:dataTable и h:column на p:column, почему то перестает возвращать данные для заполнения таблицы - no records found.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала подключаем саму библиотеку:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
      ^^^^^^^
```

Далее используем компонент [p:dataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml):

```
<p:dataTable value="#{customerBean.all}" var="customer"
             styleClass="customers">
   <p:column headerText="#{msgs.customerIdHeader}">
      <h:outputText value="#{customer.id}" />        
   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="#{msgs.NDOKHeader}">
      <h:outputText value="#{customer.NDOK}" /> 
   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="#{msgs.SODRABHeader}">
       <h:outputText value="#{customer.SODRAB}" /> 
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

В приведенном примере назначили таблице класс `customers`. Его и используем для темизации отдельных элементов таблицы. Список доступных стандартных классов для каждого элемента доступен в [документации](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf).
Например, для темизации заголовков используйте селектор `.customerTable .ui-datatable-header`.

---

Также можно добавить класс для каждой строки таблицы:

```
<p:dataTable rowStyleClass="customer-row" ...>
```

Или добавить класс для отдельной колонки:

```
<p:column headerText="#{msgs.customerIdHeader}" styleClass="customer-id-column">
```

---

Для корректной загрузки данных `ResultSet` необходимо преобразовать в `List<Customer>` и возвращать его. Пример:

```
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
...
while (resultSet.next()) {
    Customer c = new Customer();
    c.setId(resultSet.getString("ID"));
    c.setNDOKHeader(resultSet.getString("NDOK"));
    ...
    customers.add(c);
}
...
return items;
```

Comment: Использовал оба фрагмента кода, вроде бы должно все быть нормально, но нет - выдает пустую таблицу, хоть и с полностью подключенным интерфейсом.

Comment: Если таблица пустая, значит не поступают данные для заполнения. Проверьте, что в `customerBean` есть метод `getAll()`, который возвращает список объектов. Если есть метод, то проверьте, что он вызывается. Убедитесь, что возвращаемый список не является пустым. Без кода сложно что-то сказать.

Comment: Да, конечно. Дополнил в вопросе.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.